# Rounding numeric output with str.format

Tags: python, rounding, string-formatting

I'm a bit frustrated when I use Python's `str.format` function

```
for i in range(10):
    print "{0:.1f} -> {0:.0f}".format(i+.5)
```

and getting this output:

```
0.5 -> 0
1.5 -> 2
2.5 -> 2
3.5 -> 4
4.5 -> 4
5.5 -> 6
6.5 -> 6
7.5 -> 8
8.5 -> 8
9.5 -> 10
```

I expected that the decimal `5` would be rounded up, or, to be honest, this is what I need.

What is the rule behind this rounding behaviour, or is it undefined, (where) is it documented? I could not find it.

But much more important: How can I get I want? I expected that to be easy in Python, but I don't see this simple solution. Have I to switch to `Decimal` for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) function:

```
for i in range(10):
    print "{} -> {}".format(i+.5, round(i+.5))
```

Output:

```
0.5 -> 1.0
1.5 -> 2.0
2.5 -> 3.0
3.5 -> 4.0
4.5 -> 5.0
5.5 -> 6.0
6.5 -> 7.0
7.5 -> 8.0
8.5 -> 9.0
9.5 -> 10.0
```

Comment: Okay, this seems easy and explicit. I did expect this to be built in.

Comment: This is correct for python 2.x however in 3.x the round function will round to the closest multiple of 10 and if they are equally close then it will round to the even.  Values would then be: 0.5 -> 0.0
1.5 -> 2.0
2.5 -> 2.0
3.5 -> 4.0
4.5 -> 4.0
5.5 -> 6.0
6.5 -> 6.0
7.5 -> 8.0
8.5 -> 8.0
9.5 -> 10.0

Comment: That is true, but he used `print` as a statement, so I'm pretty sure he is using Python2.  How could it be fixed for Python3?

Comment: @Gratzy Yes, how would you do accomplish the same (round down for 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, round up for 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) in Python 3?

Comment: @Wolf: The simplest thing I can come up with is to define your own rounding function: `def myround(x): return (x // 1)+((x%1)>=0.5)`